# Showing and closing multiple windows

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Say I have two WPF Windows. WindowA and WindowB. Each Window has two buttons. A Open button which will SHOW the other Window and a Close button that will Close the other Window (vice versa).

Example WindowA I have the following click event and sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       WindowB.Show()
       CloseWeAidWindow()
    End Sub
    Public Sub CloseWeAidWindow()
        Dim CloseWindow = Window.GetWindow(Me)
        If CloseWindow IsNot Nothing Then
            CloseWindow.Close()
            GC.Collect()
        End If
    End Sub
```

However it closes the entire application and not just WindowA. WindowB opens for about .5 seconds.

How can I open another window and close the current window?

Comment: I guess your `WindowA` is the main message loop, closing it means destroying the main message loop and the application will be shutdown, try `Hiding` it instead. We don't need to close it.

Comment: Ah yes. Hiding works. My main concern is performance. Window A and B both have 4 images that display when they are open. If I hide WindowA wouldn't the apps memory usage increase?

Comment: because Window A is not properly being disposed*

Comment: I am new and I am in the middle of learning. Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your [`Application.ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) is set to `OnMainWindowClose`. If you want to the app to remain open as long as any window is visible try `OnLastWindowClose`.